# Bar plot in PGF plots with no upper limit

Tags: pgfplots

I assesed particke size distribution using sieve analysis. Now I want to present the results using PGFplots. The largest opening was 1 mm. I can plot finite intervals (e.g. 0.25 mm -- 0.50 mm), but I don't know how to plot '1 mm and larger', I have to give a finite upper bound.

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.05]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    grid=none, 
    xlabel={średnica oczek [\si{\milli\meter}]},
    ylabel={masa [\si{\gram}]}, 
    minor y tick num=9, 
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}
                        ]
    \addplot[] table[x=sred, y=masa] {cw4.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

cw4.dat:

```
sred    masa
0.000   0.18
0.125   0.72
0.250   1.11
0.500   1.04
1.000   0.02
2.000   0.02
```

2.000 is the upper bound for the last interval, but the last interval should have no upper bound and I don't know how to do it in PGFplots.

This is what I have:

[image: This is what I have]

This is what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: There is an `inf` operator in `pgfplots` (it behaves like a number), but I cannot try it right now if it fits to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the `xticklabel` depending on the value of the current xtick

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick<1?
  "\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber\noexpand\tick--\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber\noexpand\nexttick"
  :"$\noexpand>1$"}\pgfmathresult}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar interval,
      grid=none, 
      xlabel={średnica oczek [\si{\milli\meter}]},
      ylabel={masa [\si{\gram}]}, 
      minor y tick num=9, 
      xtick=data,
      x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}, 
      xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick<1?
        "\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber\noexpand\tick--\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber\noexpand\nexttick"
        :"$\noexpand>1$"}\pgfmathresult}
      ]
      \addplot[] table[x=sred, y=masa] {cw4.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution seems to work, unfortunately I use \usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
which seem incompatible with your solution

Comment: Then you have to load the tikzlibrary `babel` in addition. I have changed the code.